# setting a custom facebook share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I'm trying to set facebook custom share button instead of default one.
This code is from the [official fb page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://mementocosmicum.16mb.com" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmementocosmicum.16mb.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
</div>
```

Clicking on the link a share popup appears. I added an `id` to the above link, this way:

```
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" id='fbshare' target="...
```

**js**

```
$('#sharefb').click(function(){ // my custom button
    $('#fbshare').click();
});
```

And expecting the popup to appear but it doesn't.

Comment: When the JS SDK runs, it replaces the content of that div element with an iframe - the link element does not even exist any more after that. // You are trying to trigger a click event - what does that have to do with _“trying to set facebook custom share button instead of default one”_?